# Execute a function with an ng-click, but the second function, execute it if it meets condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently validating a form. I have a function called "myFunction".

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" ng-click='form.$valid && myFunction()'>SEND</button>
```

I want the function to run when is clicked, if the form is valid, ie if

```
Form.$valid == true.
```

the function "myFunction()" is executed.

I have other function, called "directive_function()". I need execute always this function, when is clicked this button, but the second function "directive_function()" only if the condition is is fulfilled.

I need to do this directly in the html view, I should not and do not want to put anything in the controller. How can I do it?

more or less I need:

```
ng-click='directive_function(); form.$valid && myFunction()'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4973nesL/

Comment: Why do you not want this done in the controller?

Comment: Why not make a method that does it all?

Comment: @BenBeck I try to do this generically, to use it in any template, and have no need to modify each controller.

Comment: Why not create an attribute directive? It would be reusable and accomplish the same thing you're trying to do. Then the logic is written once in that directive's controller.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be doing this from your view. You should restructure this in order to move the logic into your controller. You can do something like:

```
<button ng-click='directive_function();'>SEND</button>
```

and in your controller

```
directive_function() {
  if(...) {
    // only execute function if your condition is met
    myFunction();
  }
}
```